# i want to insert data in mongodb after all promises have been done by using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, promise

i am pushing errors in array by using promises but before it push errors in array it check the condition for insert data like in else i am inserting data.

```
var errorsArr= [];

var username = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    User.findOne({ "username": req.body.username },function(err,user){
        if(err)
            reject(err);

        if(user) {
            resolve(1);
        }else{
            resolve(0);
        }
    });
});
username.then(function(data){
    if( data == 1 )
        errorsArr.push({"msg": "Username already been taken."});
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});

var email = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    User.findOne({ "email": req.body.email },function(err,user){
        if(err)
            reject(err);

        if(user) {
            resolve(1);
        }else{
            resolve(0);
        }
    });
});
email.then(function(data){
    if( data == 1 )
        errorsArr.push({"msg": "email already been taken."});
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});

if(errorsArr.length >0)
{
    req.session.error = errorsArr;
    return  res.redirect('/auth/Registration');
}
else {
    var newUser = new User();
    newUser.username = req.body.username;
    newUser.password = req.body.password;
    newUser.sex = req.body.sex;
    newUser.email = req.body.email;
    newUser.phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
    newUser.age = req.body.age;
    newUser.designation = req.body.designation;
    newUser.timing = req.body.timing;
    var CurrentDate = moment.tz(new Date(req.body.joiningDate), "Asia/Karachi").unix();
    newUser.joiningDate = CurrentDate;
    newUser.save(function (err, user) {
        if (!err)
            return res.redirect('/auth/Login');
    });
}
```

can you please help me to do it in better way i am new in node.js. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise.all is your solution. It waits for all the promises.

```
 Promise.all([p1,p2,..]).then(function() {
      // all loaded
  }, function() {
   // one or more failed
 });
```

Reference Link:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing asynchronous and synchronous code.

Synchronous:

```
var errorsArr= [];
```

Asynchronous:

```
var username = new Promise(...{
  ...
});
username.then(..
  errorsArr.push(...);
})
```

Synchronous:

```
if (errorsArr.length > 0) {
    ...
```

The asynchronous part in the middle (where you do `errorsArr.push(…)`) doesn't actually happen *before* your synchronous code at the end (`if (errorsArr.length > 0)`).

You need to convert all your synchronous code to asynchronous as well, if you want it to execute in succession to the other async code.

Other answers have already explained that how, which is by using `Promise.all`

I would also like to suggest using [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) Promise library which offers [promisification](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html) so you can just promisify your mongoose models, instead of manually creating promises for every operation.

```
Promise.promisifyAll(User);
var username = User.findOneAsync(...); // the new "findOneAsync"  method returns a promise
username.then(data => ...)
```

You might also wanna checkout the upcoming ES2016 additions to javascript that further simplify promises with async/await. With it you can get rid of `.then(..)` entirely and just write:

```
app.get('/', async function(req, res) { // < async function
    try {
        var username = await User.findOneAsync(...); // await statements
        var email = await User.findOneAsync(...);
        // do stuff
    } catch(err){
        // handle errors
    }
});
```

[Checkout this great article on async/await](http://pouchdb.com/2015/03/05/taming-the-async-beast-with-es7.html). Although this requires you add an extra transpilation step by using Babel or Typescript. There's also the recently released [Microsoft's fork of Node](https://github.com/Microsoft/node/releases) that ships with chakra engine (instead of V8) which already supports async/await as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
  Promise.all([
Reservation.find({'parking.owner': req.payload.id}).exec(),
Reservation.count({'parking.owner': req.payload.id}).exec(),
Reservation.aggregate([
   { $match: {
        _id: req.payload.id
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        total: { $sum: "$price"  }
    }}
    ])
  ]).then(results=>{
     const list = results[0]
     const count = results[1]
     const sum = results[2]
     res.status(200).json({list,count,sum});
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

after **all** **Promises** have been done ... use `Promise.all`

the checking for errors at the bottom of your code could be written:

```
Promise.all([username, email])
.then(function(results) {
    if(errorsArr.length >0)
    {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
});
```

Quickest and easiest change to your code - refactoring your code can make it even sleeker

Answer (score 0):

@Jaromanda X answer is correct if there is username and email checks are independent and no order has to be followed. Else, you have to do a promise chain.